# Virtual Host directives disappearing from the httpd.conf file

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, virtualhost

Occasionally, I notice that the Virtual Host directives literally disappear from inside the httpd.conf file.  The domains still redirect correctly, however I can't see (or edit) the directives anymore.  What could cause this?

I am running Apache on a CentOS system.

Comment: There are any number of things that can cause this, making the question impossible to answer correctly. Look for cron jobs, puppet/chef/cfengine, webmin/plesk/cpanel, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Adminitration instruments, such as Webmin or similar, configure your system by parsing and modifying system files.